# Vim function to get all mappings

Tags: vim

Is there a function in Vim to get the list of all current mappings as a dictionary?  (I know about `:map` command.)

If no (it seems so), is there a decent workaround?

Here is the practical motivation for this question: i would like to be able to clear all key mappings except those that start with `<Plug>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing I could see either. You could use `:redir` to get the map output into a register and manipulate that. This snippet of vim script will do the job:

```
redir @a
silent map
redir END
let l = split(@a, '\n')
```

Now `l` contains a list of mappings, though parsing each entry might be a pain.

To filter these for those not containing `<Plug>` add this line:

```
call filter(l, 'v:val !~ "<Plug>"')
```

An example of a script to unmap non-`<Plug>` entries could be:

```
redir @a
silent map
redir end
let l = split(@a, '\n')
call filter(l, 'v:val !~ "<Plug>"')
for line in l
    let type = line[0]
    let thekey = split(line[1:len(line)], ' \+')[0]
    try
        exec type. 'unmap '. thekey
    catch /E31/
    endtry
endfor
```